# How can I get the list of no foreign key constraint?

Tags: sql-server, database, foreign-keys

I can get the list of foreign key constraints with a given table name by using

```
EXEC sp_fkeys 'TableName'
```

But I need to get the list of all tables which have no foreign key constraints to other tables.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what? I'm unclear!!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I edited the content and I hope it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query below gives you all tables that don't have a Foreign Key

```
SELECT s.name [Schema], t.name [Table]
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
    ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT
    1
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS fk
WHERE fk.parent_object_id = t.[object_id]);
```

This logic is inspired from a set of related queries posted at [this site](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3402/over-40-queries-to-find-sql-server-tables-with-or-without-a-certain-property/).

Comment: Thank you so much! Very useful website, I will definitely bookmark it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using EXCEPT.

```
select name
from sys.tables
except
(
    select OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)
    from sys.foreign_keys
)
order by name
```

Comment: One thing I did notice. This will not correctly identify tables if you have the same name in multiple schemas. If one of those tables had a foreign key and the other doesn't it will still be returned by this query.

Comment: Thanks for the notification. I am working with a single schema, so it worked at the moment. I will keep that on my mind for the future.